# center aligned div isnt actually center

Tags: css, center, fluid-layout

okay i have a div nested inside another div and the inner div is centered with 80% width. but its not fully centered.

how would i make it fully centered?

http://jsfiddle.net/xx8hx/

http://postimage.org/image/15linq5yc/

## html

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Contact</h1>
    <form action="/cgi-bin/cgiemail" method="post">
      <table width="50%" border="0" cellpadding="5" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" width="50%">First Name</td>
          <td><input name="FirstName" type="text" id="fname" size="25" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

## css

```
.wrap {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
.content {
    width:80%;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:15px;
    background:url(../images/contentback.png);
    border-radius:7px;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried making a jsfiddle?  Seems like this would make it REALLY easy for people to help you.

Comment: sorry ill make one hold on pleasee

Comment: i was trying to avoid jsfiddle for this cause the html is nested so many times

Comment: made a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/drC9C/

Comment: @gar_onn I don't see anything wrong with that in Chrome.

Comment: i think he was just make the jsfiddle for me. and I use chrome, its still of centered

Comment: can you give us your fiddle, in my browder (chrome 14) it looks fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This padding line in your css is causing the box to be off-centered.

```
/* stop do not edit */
#contact>div {
    padding:50px 20px;
}
```

Getting rid of the left/right margin on that line (even though the comment told me not to) fixed it for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/4AX5b/

Comment: Hmm okay thank you I didn't think that would be it. Lol The stop do not edit was just for the main layout it wasn't meant for you to not edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your CSS:

```
body, 
html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RrCzk/).

Comment: still nothing, im really not sure why its doing this.

Answer (score 0):

found it:

```
/* stop do not edit */
#contact>div {
    pading: 50px 20px;
}
```

causes the error it should be:

```
#contact > div {
padding: 50px 0;
}
```